# Contradiction between two circuit simulators in measuring open loop gain

Tags: circuit-analysis, simulation, feedback, negative-feedback

I am implementing what I've learned over the past couple of days. This relates mainly to the simulation of a voltage regulator.

I built the (roughly) same circuit in both TINA TI and LTspice to determine the value of the loop gain of the circuit.

The results are quite different. For the TINA TI simulation the loop gain is 43dB, while for the LTspice simulation the loop gain is 56dB. One is within the desired design parameters, the other is not.

I've implemented the sims with both the traditional breaking the loop + test voltage, as well as with voltage injection (?).

**TINA TI sim**:

[image]

The results are as follows:

circuit on the left: 148.4
circuit on the right: 147.8

**LTspice sim:**

[image]

LTspice results:
[image]

**Where am I wrong and why?**

EDIT 1: I did try and change the beta of transistors to see if there any differences between TINA TI, but the impact was minimal.

EDIT 2: I did try to set the inductor and capacitor to be 1TH/1TF, but it didn't work. Also changed the values in the TINA simulation and I did not sight any difference.

EDIT 3:
I replaced the error amplifier with a Voltage Controlled Voltage Source and decided to compare the results between TINA and LTspice. The results were very close to each other. Simulated circuit is shown below:

LTspice sim:
[image]

TINA sim:
[image]

So I'd say the problem is not with the method of finding loop gain, but something about the way the sims treat the more complex circuit?

Comment: 1 megahenry does not equal 1 terahenry

Comment: The LTspice simulation behaves suspiciously when I set the inductance and capacitance at 1 Tera something.

Comment: Try setting Tina to 1 megahenry then. It probably won't make much difference but, it looks like an anomaly at the moment.

Comment: Just tried it, no difference from the initial results.

Comment: I'd suggest using native primitives for measuring loop gain. If a given SPICE program does not provide them, or doesn't document it, I suggest not using it for this simulation. Furthermore, the results are quite useless anyway, since in a real circuit the temperature differences and mismatches between transistors will drive performance of the circuit. In other words, in practice the gain spread you'll get at various operating temperatures and transistor parameter spreads will vastly exceed the "difference" you're seeing between simulated values that don't represent reality well anyway.

Comment: And furthermore - if the input voltage will vary, the gain changes due to that alone will swamp everything else. And also - the DC results won't be all that useful if the thing won't be stable, and as shown, there's no compensation and I'd think it will not be stable at a sufficiently high input voltage. Oh, and try with a capacitive load - rather typical for voltage regulators. And also: you're measuring gain with almost no DC load. As it is, the gain will be very poor if you load it up with 100mA say.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica auch. When you say native primitives do you mean controlled sources, like Voltage Controlled Current Source ?

Comment: @Virgil_Tibbs No, I mean a native primitive that breaks the loop and allows getting a Bode plot. Alas, as it stands, the circuit is not very useful for simulation, since open circuit DC gain will vary wildly across load current and input voltages. So much so, that a Zener diode with an emitter follower would work similarly "well". I really suggest trying it out on the breadboard. And make sure you got a couple dozen transistors handy. You'll probably smoke a few. Thermal runaway is a thing in reality, in SPICE - not so much unless you explicitly add a thermal overlay to the model.

Comment: How would you resolve these issues? Furthermore in what context would the analysis of the loop gain be useful?

Comment: I am confused.  You are using two different methods to measure loop gain: 1. inserted test voltage, and 2. breaking the loop.  These are being simulated by two different simulators: 1. TINA and 2. LTspice.  So you should have four (4) results for the parameter you are measuring - and shall we assume this is at DC, not some other frequency?   || Please advise: is the difference (43dB vs 56dB) between the two methods or between the two simulators, or something else?

Comment: While I can't say why the two simulators give very different results, I am interested to know whether, for just just one of the simulators, you obtain similar gain measurements in the two different test regimes - breaking the loop and inserted test signal. For instance, in Tina, do those the gain measurements concur? When inserting a test signal (left circuits), you require very high input impedance on one side (diff amp transistor base), and the response side (divider R1,R2) to have very low impedance. Otherwise the test signal is modulating potential on *both* sides...

Comment: In these circuits, impedance looking into the transistor base is comparable with output impedance of the divider resistors, and for the left circuits I don't think you can trust the gain calculation. The right hand circuit seems to be more appropriate approach, since the test voltage source is modulating *only* the transistor base, and the divider junction is not loaded in any way.

Comment: @FabioBarone I've updated the question with the values for each of the simulation. 43dB is the loop gain I observed in both simulations of the circuit in TINA. 56dB is what I observed in the LTspice simulation.

Comment: @SimonFitch "For instance, in Tina, do those the gain measurements concur?" Yes, they are: 43.42dB vs 43.39dB. That holds also for the LTspice sims.

Comment: Changing the beta of the transistors won't have much effect, in my experience.  Referring to the LTspice left ckt, what will affect loop **voltage** gain is (a) transconductance of the diff input stage Q1 & Q2 and (b) the "load" at the collector of Q12, which is comprised of Q11 collector impedance, and the base impedance of Q12.   In my experience, it is the differences in the collector impedance parameters of BJT models are the most likely culprit.   Suggest making a very simple "test-rig" in both TINA and LTspice to see the voltage gain of Q1, Q2 & Q11 (include the bias but leave out Q12).

Comment: @Virgil_Tibbs Why are the feedback resistor ratios different between the different simulations? Also, name the nodes. V(n007) is meaningless.

Comment: @qrk Better? What do you mean by different resistor ratios. All resistors are identical.

Comment: In addition to BF and BR, Early effect is also a contributor here, and perhaps terminal resistances (RC, RB, RE) too. Also verify that simulation settings are similar, including analysis method where applicable (LTspice in particular has a "modified" solver that notably produces "good enough" results, but if you're looking for binary compatibility you're going to have a hard time) (I don't recall if this different applies to AC analysis specifically, or transient only.) Also have you verified that the bias conditions are right (voltages reasonable, nothing saturated, currents equal)?

Comment: @TimWilliams verified, the transistors are properly biased. Changed the betas in the TINA TI sim to match those of the LTspice models, but still no change.

Comment: @Virgil_Tibbs Sorry about that, the top schematic values are difficult to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the difference is due to the BJT models being slightly different between TINA and LTspice.  The parameter values to compare would be those that determine the following static (DC) transfer functions:

1. base voltage to collector current, and
2. collector current to collector voltage.

The LTspice help file explains this as follows:

> The DC model is defined by the parameters Is, Bf, Nf, Ise, Ikf, and Ne which determine the forward current gain characteristics, Is, Br, Nr, Isc, Ikr, and Nc which determine the reverse current gain characteristics, and Vaf and Var which determine the output conductance for forward and reverse regions.  Three ohmic resistances Rb, Rc and Re, are included, where Rb can be high current dependent.

Listing these parameters from the help file in the groups as mentioned above:
Group 1:
Is Transport saturation current
Bf Ideal maximum forward beta
Nf Forward current emission coefficient
Ise B-E leakage saturation current
Ikf Corner for forward beta high current roll-off
Ne B-E leakage emission coefficient

Group 2:
Br Ideal maximum reverse beta
Nr Reverse current emission coefficient
Isc B-C leakage saturation current
Ikr Corner for reverse beta high current roll-off
Nc B-C leakage emission coefficient

Group 3:
Vaf Forward Early voltage
Var Reverse Early voltage

Group 4:
Rb Zero-bias base resistance
Re Emitter resistance
Rc Collector resistance

The above parameters affect the **static** transfer characteristics (zero frequency) of input voltage (Vb) to output voltage (Vc), I have deliberately omitted temperature dependencies, and parameters that affect dynamic behaviour, such as:-
Vtf Voltage describing Vbc dependence of Tf

To see if it is the simulator or the model causing the gain difference you are seeing, I suggest copy the BJT models from one simulator to the other and see if the results are identical.  Then compare the two original BJT models, looking at the values for the parameters mentioned above, to see what differences there are.

Getting accurate models for BJTs is non-trivial, here are some good starting points:
[How do I find or calculate BJT parameters for LTspice?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/649793/how-do-i-find-or-calculate-bjt-parameters-for-ltspice)

[References for writing spice model code?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/461495/references-for-writing-spice-model-code/)

Comment: Yeah, that was it.  The biggest influence seems to be the early voltage, which I guess makes sense as the loop gain depends on the output impedance of the transistors in the current mirror/ differential pair.

Comment: OK, good.  So did the two simulators, TINA and LTspice, give the same results when the models were identical?

An upvote would be nice.  :-)

Comment: First of all, thank you! Yes, when using the models from TINA in LTspice the loop gain was identical to the original simulation in TINA.  What annoys me terribly at the moment is that the quality of my voltage regulator depends on the early voltage of the transistors.

Comment: No worries.  Yes, the early voltage (aka the output impedance) of small signal transistors is definitely non-ideal.  Ideally, it should be infinite - so that a small change in current results in a large voltage swing.  Alas, in practise, the output impedance is far less than infinite.  And it seems that BJT physics conspires against us - BJT construction techniques that increase transconductance seem to reduce output impedance, and vice-versa.

Comment: Suggestion: try a cascode (common-base) between the diff pair and their load transistor.   This is an old trick to try to increase gain.  However, you may find it has little effect at low frequencies, but may be very beneficial at higher frequencies.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/535843/definition-of-cascode

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But I am afraid there's a limit to how many transistors I can use for this project. And I've already used quite a lot of parts for such a bad voltage regulator :)

Comment: @Virgil_Tibbs  Is there any reason you are not using an op-amp?

Comment: The assignment prohibits the use of integrated circuits :) And to make a simple discrete op amp to plug in the voltage regulator would probably be even more work than it's warranted. It would be so much simpler with an op amp. I could perform some stability analysis and actually understand it. It is what it is

Answer (score 0):

Just tried now with [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for simulating the circuit. It appears I should be more careful to transistor model parameters.